# Rotating an enemy sprite to face direction of movement

Tags: rotation, angle, direction

I'm making a top down 2d tank game using allegro as part of a university project and I'm currently setting up the AI movement of the enemies,

I've got most of the game built and these are just finishing touches at the moment, I've got the tanks cannon always facing the player, and the movement of the tank itself working, but I need to work out how to rotate the enemy tank to face its direction of travel.

Comment: What is your exact problem: how to rotate the sprite, or how to determin the angle?

Comment: A bit of both, ive got my enemy sprite moving around on its own, and i have the cannon of the enemy sprite turning to face the player as you move yourself around, but the body of the enemy sprite doesnt turn as it drives around, it just stays static.

I'm looking for a way to make the body turn as it moves, so its always facing forwards with its motion